# Cannot use r.net within a wcf service

Tags: c#, r, wcf, r.net

I am trying to set up an `R.net` WCF service as a server to run R commands on.

I have set up a test WinForms application where everything works.

This is how I use it:

```
void init()
{
    SetupPath()
    engine = REngine.GetInstanceFromID("test");
    if (engine == null) engine = REngine.CreateInstance("test");
    engine.Initialize();
}
...
    results.Add(engine.Evaluate(command).AsCharacter().ToArray());
```

I created an equivalent WCF service which should work exactly the same;

`REngine.CreateInstance()` returns a valid `REngine` object,
`engine.Initialize()` silently crashes my service. Try-Catch section is ignored so I cannot see what exactly is happening.

- What is the correct way to use `R.net` within a WCF service?
- What could be the reason of different behaviours?
- Where can I see detailed logs of the crash?
- Service calls which don't use `R.net` complete successfully.

Both winforms test application and WCF service are 64 bit (i need them to be). (I did not manage to set up a 64-bit IIS express application, so am using IIS instead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not manage to find the reason of the problem, however, switching to `R.NET.Community` package did the trick.